# Opening in-memory image with Pillow raises `TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface`

Tags: python, flask, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I'm reading an image, encoding it to base64, and sending it as part of a payload to a Flask app.  In the app, the string gets decoded and checked for validity by loading it with `PIL.Image` and `io.BytesIO`.  When I run the steps in a shell, they execute correctly.  When I run the server and pass the data from the client, I get `TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface`.  Why do I get this error and how do I fix it?

```
with open(args.pngfile) as f:
    payload['image'] = f.read().encode('base64')
requests.post(URL, json=payload, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

```
image_str = request.json['image']
decoded_image_str = image_str.decode('base64')
Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded_image_str))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/parin.porecha/image_service/image_service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/parin.porecha/image_service/image_service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/parin.porecha/image_service/image_service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/parin.porecha/image_service/image_service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/parin.porecha/image_service/image_service_venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "./application.py", line 35, in compress
    response = compress(request)
  File "./processor.py", line 56, in compress
    Image.open(io.BytesIO(decoded_image_str))
TypeError: 'unicode' does not have the buffer interface
```

```
Python 2.7.3
Flask 0.10.1
Pillow 2.9.0
```

Comment: A string value stored in a JSON dict is not a bytestream.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, sorry the usage remained from brain-storming phase. I've corrected the instances to 'encoded string'

Comment: I suggest that maybe your server is running Python 3 and not 2.7.3. Otherwise `decode('base64')` should *not* be creating a Unicode object.